# SQL to select distinct values from table with foreign key

Tags: sql

I have two tables: `A` (`a_id` as int, some string fields...) and `B` (`b_id`, string field "name" and referenced column `a_id`).
I want to select unique values from the table `A` where `B.name` `LIKE` "%somestring%".

Comment: What queries did you try and how did the result differ from what you wanted?

Comment: And what flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: SELECT a.id, a.somedata
from tablea a
left join tableb b 
on b.a_id=a.id
where b.name like '%somestring%'

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM TableB b 
   WHERE a.a_id = b.a_id
    AND  b.name LIKE "%somestring%"
)
```

Comment: I get only one row instead of all.

Comment: Show some sample data in your question.

Comment: Table b contains two rows referencing the same a.id. Now, I want to select that a.id row in all cases where b.name LIKE "%somestring%". And so on, for all a.id rows where condition is true. So -to get distinct a.ids.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [inner join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) to do this.

select A.a_id, B.b_id,  from A inner join B on A.a_id = B.a_id where B.Name LIKE '%somestring%'

Comment: But if table B is a _child_-table of A it can contain mutiple rows per A-Row. OP wants to avoid that according to the title.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i did not see that, but you can just add 'distinct'. I've updated my answer